# center div on screen no matter window size

Tags: css

This may be a super easy css question, but I cannot center the main area without using margin-left. Is there a better solution to center this on the screen--no matter what size the window is? I think part of the issue is that the box is 1300px. Yes- it needs to be that size.

```css
#mainContent{
  
//margin-left: 400px !important;

width:1300px;
height:800px;
border:2px solid #f6f6f6;
background-color:black;
 

}
```

```html
<div id="mainContent">

</div>
```

Comment: Center vertically **and** horizontally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try `margin: 0 auto;`? It should center the div.

```css
#mainContent{
  
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:2px solid #f6f6f6;
  background-color:black;
  margin: 0 auto;
 

}
```

```html
<div id="mainContent">

</div>
```

Comment: the width is 1300px

Comment: Ok? ... So if the screen is less than 1300px the div will be on the left of your screen stuck. That **is** centered....

Comment: You may also need a `display: block;` to get `margin: 0 auto;` to work correctly.

Comment: You _may_, you may.

Comment: I just needed to add the !important after the auto

Comment: @user2557504 you may want to figure out _why_ you needed the important flag -- you may have some overriding css.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#mainContent{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:1300px;
  height:800px;
  border:2px solid #f6f6f6;
  background-color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the content is not responsive, and you want cropping when the window is less than 1300px wide, here's another option:

```
#mainContent{
  ...
  margin-left: calc(50% - 650px);
}
```

Here's an example of it in play: https://jsfiddle.net/yvwnvmsf/1/

Answer (score -2):

```css
#mainContent{
  
display:flex;
min-height:100vh;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
border:2px solid #f6f6f6;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContent">
    <font>Like this?</font >
</div>
```